# Does JavaScript append function refuse to add the duplicate element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I plan to add each element of toDos to a list, but only the last element is displayed from the list.

I know that the following line of code causes the problem, but not understand the reason.

```
$tag_li= $tag_li.text(toDo);
```

**My code:**

```js
 var $organizedByTag=[ { "name":"shopping", "toDos":["Get groceries","HAHA","HEIHEI"]
}, {
  "name": "chores",
  "toDos": ["Get groceries", "Take Gracie to the park"]
}];
$organizedByTag.forEach(function (Tag) {
  var $tag_ul = $(" <ul > "); 
  var $tag_li=$(" <li > "); 
  $tag_head=$(" <h3 >").text(Tag.name); Tag.toDos.forEach(function(toDo){ $tag_li= $tag_li.text(toDo);
  $tag_ul.append($tag_li);
}); 
$(".content").append($tag_head); $(".content").append($tag_ul);
});
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Get Groceries</li>
    <li>Make up some new ToDos</li>
    <li>Prep for Monday's class</li>
    <li>Answer recruiter emails on Linkedin</li>
    <li>Take Gracie to the park</li>
    <li>Finish writing book</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why you name all your variables starting with `$`? This isn't PHP

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var $tag_li = $("<li>");` inside the `Tag.toDos.forEach(function(toDo) {` function.This is because for every element in array a `li` should be created. Here only one `li` is getting created and the previous text of `li` is replaced by the last one.

```js
var $organizedByTag = [{
    "name": "shopping",
    "toDos": ["Get groceries", "HAHA", "HEIHEI"]
  },
  {
    "name": "chores",
    "toDos": ["Get groceries", "Take Gracie to the park"]
  }


];

$organizedByTag.forEach(function(Tag) {
  var $tag_ul = $("<ul>");

  $tag_head = $("<h3>").text(Tag.name);
  Tag.toDos.forEach(function(toDo) {
    var $tag_li = $("<li>");
    $tag_li = $tag_li.text(toDo);

    $tag_ul.append($tag_li);

  });

  $(".content").append($tag_head);
  $(".content").append($tag_ul);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Get Groceries</li>
    <li>Make up some new ToDos</li>
    <li>Prep for Monday's class</li>
    <li>Answer recruiter emails on Linkedin</li>
    <li>Take Gracie to the park</li>
    <li>Finish writing book</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only create the `tag_li` once, then later rewrite its text and add it to the ul again. You need to create a new one for each item.

This should fix it:

```js
var $organizedByTag = [{
    "name": "shopping",
    "toDos": ["Get groceries", "HAHA", "HEIHEI"]
  },
  {
    "name": "chores",
    "toDos": ["Get groceries", "Take Gracie to the park"]
  }


];

$organizedByTag.forEach(function(Tag) {
  var $tag_ul = $("<ul>");
  $tag_head = $("<h3>").text(Tag.name);
  Tag.toDos.forEach(function(toDo) {
    var $tag_li = $("<li>");
    $tag_li = $tag_li.text(toDo);

    $tag_ul.append($tag_li);

  });

  $(".content").append($tag_head);
  $(".content").append($tag_ul);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Get Groceries</li>
    <li>Make up some new ToDos</li>
    <li>Prep for Monday's class</li>
    <li>Answer recruiter emails on Linkedin</li>
    <li>Take Gracie to the park</li>
    <li>Finish writing book</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

P.S.: You don't need the `$` for the variable names.